# Showing x-axis labels on histogram plot for interval cuts using R

Tags: r

Does anyone know why the labels are not showing on x-axis based on the following code:

```
set.seed(50)
data <- sample(50)

res <- cut(data, breaks = seq(0,50, by= 12), labels = c("<12","12-24","24-35","36-50"))

hist(as.numeric(res))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try with `barplot(table(res))`

Comment: @Duck no that solution didn't work

Comment: Why do you think labels should appear with numerical data, have you looked into `as.numeric(res)`?

Comment: Without as.numeric, I got this error: "Error in hist.default(result) : 'x' must be numeric"